# javascript calculation on calculating once a client clicks on a form option

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am doing a small project on creating an order form.
I am trying to display the price per page once the client selects the time.

For example if the selected time is 4hour it should return 12usd.. if its 6hours it should return 10 usd......

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class=" custom-select" style="width:200px;">
    <select class="form-control" id="time">
      <option value="0">Time...</option>
      <option value="1">4hrs</option>
      <option value="2">6hrs</option>
      <option value="3">1day</option>
      <option value="4">2days</option>
      <option value="5">3days</option>
      <option value="6">4days</option>
      <option value="7">5days</option>
      <option value="8">6days</option>
      <option value="9">7days</option>
      <option value="10">After 7 days</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="bmd-label-floating">cpp</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpp">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Where does the price come from? What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make something like this.

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.ice-cream');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const result = document.querySelector('.result');
  result.textContent = `You like ${event.target.value}`;
});
```

```html
<label>Choose an ice cream flavor:
  <select class="ice-cream" name="ice-cream">
    <option value="">Select One …</option>
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="sardine">Sardine</option>
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
  </select>
</label>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Nice example but why not use OP's own code like [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67367195/295783)?

Answer (score 0):

So you won't tell us in details so we have to guess

```js
const prices = [0,12,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2],
cpp = document.getElementById('cpp'),
time = document.getElementById('time')

time.addEventListener('change',function() {
  cpp.value = prices[this.value]
})


// init if the select is already set from server
const change = new CustomEvent("change");
time.dispatchEvent(change);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class=" custom-select" style="width:200px;">
    <select class="form-control" id="time">
      <option value="0">Time...</option>
      <option value="1">4hrs</option>
      <option value="2">6hrs</option>
      <option value="3">1day</option>
      <option value="4">2days</option>
      <option value="5">3days</option>
      <option value="6">4days</option>
      <option value="7">5days</option>
      <option value="8">6days</option>
      <option value="9">7days</option>
      <option value="10">After 7 days</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="bmd-label-floating">cpp</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpp">
  </div>
</div>
```